# building libpq and pg_confing on windows with MSVC/VS19 (postgresql 13.2)

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio, visual-c++

long story short, i need pythons psycopg2 site package that depends on libpq and pg_config from postgresql. I don't need the entire postgresql just those two artifacts. on linux the build was super easy since the command line build allows to build and install only those two artifacts. Is there a simple way to do it on Windows with MSVC? some CMake port maybe? i did look at the doc for Postgresql 13.2 and its of no use for windows builds and i cant find any useful info for versions greater then 9.x

if there is at least a simple way to build the entire postgresql for windows that would be a good start.

Comment: Why don't you install the binaries? You can build psycopg2 with those.

Comment: unfortunately i need to build it due to some other dependencies later down the road and i need the compiler and env compatibility. why have it easy...

Comment: Ok. Why is it a problem to build all of PostgreSQL?

Comment: a) i dont need it
b) its a way of doing it but i need to introduce too many deps to do it and a msvc build is not straight forward
c) i like how easy it is on linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be straightforward, see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/install-windows-full.html#id-1.6.4.8.10):

> To build just a single project, for example `psql`, run the commands:
>
> ```
> build psql
> build DEBUG psql
> ```

That will also build `libpq.dll` which is required by `psql`.

Comment: ty. i just tried it again and it looks i missed some other config thats why it didnt work form me. but yeah. this is the correct solution.